# Spring Application Hangs inside Spout and bolts in storm

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-storm

In my spout I am starting a spring boot application which basically initialises all the beans and classes .

Whenever I start the topology in remote cluster , the moment this spring application runs inside the open method of my Spout , I see that the topology hangs and I see no errors  and no output in my worker logs from my application . After sometime the same messages appear in my log file (albeit with new timestamp) . What may be causing this issue in the cluster .

On Local Cluster though which i run inside my eclipse , everything works fine .

Also , Where can I see log messages from my application . I can only see log messages from Spouts and Bolts inside worker logs . But what about the other logs which my application prints . Is their something which I need to configure from my end ??

This is what I am doing inside open method for the Spout =>

```
LOG.info("Inside Synchrnized block for Storm Context");

      ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

      LOG.info("Inside Create Application Context block for Storm Context");

      SpringApplicationBuilder appBuilder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class);

      LOG.info("Loading Profiles ");

      context = (ApplicationContext) appBuilder.profiles("common","common_rabbitmq","common_mongo_db", "common_mysql_db",

                                                         "common_topology").run();

      LOG.info("Set the Storm Context ");
```

In my worker logs I can only see logs  generated as

```
  "Inside Synchrnized block for Storm Context";
 "Loading Profiles ";
```

And the application hangs after printing this . It never returns from the run method and never prints        "Set the Storm Context "

PS=> The run method here

```
appBuilder.profiles("common","common_rabbitmq","common_mongo_db", "common_mysql_db","common_topology").run();
```

is not to run it on a different thread (It is not launching it in different thread) rather it does work on the same thread Spout is running on.